# Link not firing inside Ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get a custom pop up to actually pop-up when clicked by a link inside the success.

So the user comes to Profilestatus.php and inserts a new post to their feed.
All this information is sent back via Json and the posts are constructed within my success. Ajax for that is provided below.

Within that newly constructed post is a share button.. Now when the post is constructed with Ajax and pretended into the users feed the share button doesn't fire the called div lights"streamitem_id" but i think this has something to do with the fact the Ajax call is made inside Profilestatus.php and the div that its looking for is inside the Commentspage.php

Link that calls on Client side inside commentspage.php

```
<a  style='cursor:pointer;' id="<? echo $streamitem_data['streamitem_id']; ?>" onclick = "document.getElementById('lights<? echo $streamitem_data['streamitem_id']; ?>').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" class="pop" title='Share this' href="#">Share</a></div>
```

PROFILESTATUSINPUT.PHP
The code below is what grabs the post content and has the share button attached - I have removed all the code that I don't need in the success other than the Share button that is a part of my question.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { toid: content, newmsg: newmsg, red: username, privacy: privacy},
    success: function(data){ 
    $.each(data.userpost, function(i, response) {
    $("#newmsg").text(""); 
    if (response.streamitem_type_id == 1) { 
    $("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='streamshare'><a  style='cursor:pointer;' id='"+response['streamitem_id']+"' onclick='document.getElementById(lights"+response['streamitem_id']+").style.display=block;' class='pop' title='Share this' href='"+response['streamitem_id']+")'>Share</a></div>");
    }
```

So my question is.. How do i allow the share button to call the commentspage.php from Profilestatus.php so it will find the actual div and popup,
Or maybe a better approach would suit"

Thank you for any help or advise

Comment: The link you are prepending in homestatusid looks different then commentstage.php.. there is no `style.display=block` statement in the later one

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to put that back in.. But it made no difference.

Comment: What is making you sure that it has been succeeded?

Comment: your way of displaying a popup is an awkward one.Plus in the later part you need to pass block inside appropriate quotes `style.display="block"` keeping in mind the escaping of whole string. Please refer to your browser console(firebug F12) to see if there are errors.

Comment: ReferenceError: lights898 is not defined
http://localhost/profile.php?username=me#/898 onclick Share
Line 1

Comment: And that I think is because the div is in another page??